# Problema con NavBar de bootstrap4 al publicar aplicación Aps.net MVC en IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-4

El asunto es que estoy desarrollando una aplicación y en la pantalla principal tengo un menú, realizado con `navbar` de Bootstrap 4, ejecutando la aplicación desde Visual Studio 2017, el `navbar` se muestra correctamente, cómo muestro en la siguiente imagen:

[image: NavBar mostrado al ejecutar desde VS2017 (iis express)]

Para que el cliente pueda acceder, ver los avances y dar su opinión, coloqué la aplicación en un servidor web IIS, para su posterior acceso, encontrándome que tanto en el propio servidor (Windows Server 2012) como en estaciones, el `navbar` no se muestra correctamente, muestro a continuación:

[image: NavBar mostrado al abrir la aplicación desde iis en windows server 2012]

Como pueden observar, se pierden muchos detalles del `navbar` en el IIS de windows server 2012.

Me gustaría contar con sus valiosos aportes con el fin de ver si es posible resolver éste tema, cualquier información, sección de código o lo que sea que haga falta para ayudarme, por favor indíquenme.

Comment: ¿Usaste el mismo monitor? Tal Vez los cambios sean por tamaño diferentes de pantallas

Comment: Sí, es la misma pantalla que estoy usando para las dos capturas que pasé.

Comment: Fijate si se esta cargando bien el css de bootstrap

Comment: Puedes hacer una captura de la consola del navegador? Pareciera que no esta cargando bien algun css o javascript...

Answer (score 0):

finalmente di con el problema, era cómo me dicen @JuanSalvadorPortugal y @GonzaloPigni un css que no estaba cargando correctamente. En principio asumí que era un tema con IIS.